# Is it good practice to use AccessBean or SQL to fetch data from OOTB table in IBM WCS

Tags: wcs

I want to get data from multiple OOTB WCS table for which there is no OOTB rest available. I am using multiple access bean in databean to get data from tables. Is this a good practice or we should use ServerJDBCHelperAccessBean make a single query with join to hit database. I understand that AccessBean are cached but there are techniques we can cache sql also.
Is there any other reason we should use AccessBean instead of ServerJDBCHelperAccessBean in case fetching data from multiple tables. or we should use ServerJDBCHelperAccessBean and get data in single sql query with joins.

And which will be more expensive in above approaches.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule to choose between the above two methods for database interactions. Developer has to make a logical choice

AccessBeans

Caching is one of the advantage of access beans. That is a good performance improvement and is achieved by caching the home objects as the look up for home objects are costly. Another point in favour of access bean is handling optimistic updates. Your case is to get the data (not to update/insert) and hence you are safe here.

Session Bean

Like access bean , session beans are another way of reading data from DB when you want to get data from multiple tables. A session bean must implement BASEJDBCHelper class.

```
public class  TestSessionBean extends 
com.ibm.commerce.base.helpers.BaseJDBCHelper 
implements SessionBean{
public Object  fetchResults()       throws 
javax.naming.NamingException, SQLException
{
try {
// get a connection from the WebSphere Commerce data source
makeConnection();
PreparedStatement prepStatement = getPreparedStatement( "sql to execute");
ResultSet rs = executeQuery(prepStatement, false);
}
finally {
closeConnection();
}
}
}
```

Using ServerJDBCHelperAccessBean

This is used when you have to make a db transaction outside of EJBs. Keep in mind that it is highly recommended to use EJBs for update/delete for keeping the overall integrity.

In your case, as far as I understand it is a select involving multiple tables and you are not keen on the data to be really in sync (like you are OK to lose a data which was updated nano seconds back or so). Hence you can go ahead with second or third approach

A good reference : 
http://deepakpadmakumar.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/session-beans-and-entity-beans-in-wcs.html